# Is there any way to Activate a button after Payment by Paypal is done

Tags: javascript, paypal

i want to create a button with a feature link.
You can only activate this button via paypal-payment.

There is a inactive button first, if you click you will go to paypal payment.
If the Payment is done, i want to go back to Site and the button is active now and you can click.
How can i do this with Javascript

Comment: Why do you want to do this with javascript? What do you think will happen to your site if the user disables javascript in his browser?

Answer (score 0):

You can hand over a return-URL to paypal which gets called if the payment was successful/aborted. So just do all the magic on this return-URL. No need to do this with javascript. You have to enable Auto-Return in your Account first in order for this to work.

[Paypal Auto Return](https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/mer/express_return_summary-outside)

[API Guideline](https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/US/en_US/files/developer/PP_WebsitePaymentsStandard_IntegrationGuide.pdf) - AutoReturn on Page 351;)